# Converting string to 'Ascii' encoded url format?

Tags: javascript, ascii, utf

In Javascript we have function like encodeURI and decodeURI to convert special characters in URL into UTF.
I found that there can be two encoded form of a special character based on this post - http://www.backbone.se/urlencodingUTF8.htm
So if we have 'color=红色' in URL which can be converted to 'color=%E7%BA%A2%E8%89%B2' that is in UNICODE.

So is there any function in javascript to convert special characters in URL into ascii code URL format? so 'ç' can convert to '%E7' and not into "%C3%A7"

Comment: that doesn't fit in ascii.

Comment: I mentioned that character based on the URL http://www.backbone.se/urlencodingUTF8.htm  I posted in question. So is that post wrong?

Comment: it appears that page is wrong ascii only goes up to 127, extended ascii is very ambigous, hence the browser is deferring to utf8

Comment: Then I think there must be check on websites with false information. So that people should not waste their precious time by going through the content of these websites.